# How can I understand the three-dimensional space forms?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

Here is what I know:

- A space form is defined as a manifold admitting a Riemannian manifold of constant sectional curvature
- A classical result of Cartan states that a manifold is a space form if and only if it is a quotient of $S^n$, $\mathbb{R}^n$, or $\mathbb{H}^n$ with their usual metrics by a discrete group of isometries $\Gamma$ acting properly discontinuously; furthermore $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of the space form. This reduces the space form problem to a problem in group theory.
- Such a discrete group in the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{H}^n$ are referred to respectively as Kleinian or crystallographic.
- The sphere and the real projective space are the only even-dimensional spherical space forms.

I have often seen papers in differential geometry, for example convergence results for Ricci flow [cf. Hamilton 1982 & 1986, Böhm-Wilking, Brendle-Schoen], show that manifolds admitting metrics of a certain type (e.g. of positive Ricci curvature, positive curvature operator, positive isotropic curvature) are space forms, "which have been completely classified" [cf. Wolf's book *Spaces of constant curvature*], seeming to imply that this gives a complete understanding of such manifolds.

However, even having seen such a list of groups, I don't feel that it gives me a much better understanding of space forms than what I listed above. How can I understand it better? Some sample questions: (I'm happy to restrict to the three-dimensional case for simplicity.)

- Are two space forms diffeomorphic if their fundamental groups are isomorphic? If this is not true, what if we require more of their homotopy groups to be isomorphic?
- Maybe a natural class of 3-manifolds to consider are those with locally homogeneous metrics (i.e. for any $p,q\in M$ there are neighborhoods $U_p\ni p$ and $V_q\ni q$ and an isometry $U_p\to V_q$); by a result of Singer [CPAM 1960] the universal cover of such a manifold with the pulled back metric is homogeneous and so is one of the eight geometries. If this geometry is $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ or $\widetilde{\operatorname{SL}}(2,\mathbb{R})$ then it is immediate from the second bullet point above that $M$ is not a space form; however I think (?) Nil and Sol have the topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$; so is it possible for a locally homogeneous manifold of one of these types to be a space form?
- More generally, given any closed 3-manifold, are there any generally applicable (but not too trivial) necessary or sufficient conditions to see if it is a space form, perhaps on the level of homotopy, homology, or cohomology?
- Given any compact 3-manifold $M$, when can we make $M\sharp N$ a space form for some choice of compact 3-manifold $N$?

These are just a handful of things I'm curious about. **My main question is the title.**

Answer (score 8):

> Are two space forms diffeomorphic if their fundamental groups are
>   isomorphic? If this is not true, what if we require more of their
>   homotopy groups to be isomorphic?

This is true in the hyperbolic case.  In fact more is true: in dimensions three and higher Mostow rigidity implies that if $M$ and $N$ have isomorphic fundamental groups then they are isometric.

It is false in the spherical case.  There are non-homeomorphic lens spaces with isomorphic (finite, cyclic) fundamental groups.

> Nil and Sol have the topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$; so is it possible for a locally
>   homogeneous manifold of one of these types to be a space form?

No.  If a closed three-manifold is geometric, then it has a unique geometry. (See the next answer for why.)

> More generally, given any closed 3-manifold, are there any generally
>   applicable (but not too trivial) necessary or sufficient conditions to
>   see if it is a space form, perhaps on the level of homotopy, homology,
>   or cohomology?

The class of geometric three-manifolds can be characterized topologically (mostly in terms of their JSJ decomposition) or algebraically.  Furthermore, each of the eight geometries has a topological, and also algebraic, description within this framework.  For example, a closed three-manifold is a spherical space form if and only if it has finite fundamental group. A closed three-manifold is a Euclidean space form if and only if its fundamental group has $\mathbb{Z}^3$ as a finite index subgroup.

> Given any compact 3-manifold $M$, when can we make $M \# N$ a space form for
>   some choice of compact 3-manifold $N$?

The only closed geometric three-manifold that is a connect sum is $\mathbb{RP}^3 \# \mathbb{RP}^3$. It has $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ geometry.

An over-all answer to your question might be: The hyperbolic manifolds are hugely interesting to a range of mathematicians, and are still actively being studied.

Here are some perhaps useful links.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24572/drawing-of-the-eight-thurston-geometries/30871#30871

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153325/is-there-a-criterion-for-a-link-complement-to-have-a-hyperbolic-structure-with-f/153327#153327

Comment: I don't know what you call "geometrization theorem", but clearly you don't need Perelman to know that closed manifolds with SOL or NIL geometry are not space forms.

Comment: Good point.  I'll edit that.  Thanks.

Comment: The simple argument for the given case is as follows: in the NIL and SOL cases, the fundamental group is virtually solvable and not virtually abelian; for space forms: in the hyperbolic case it's not virtually solvable, and in the Euclidean or spherical case it's virtually abelian. A more refined argument, which also separates these cases (NIL/SOL vs constant curvature) up to quasi-isometry, is that for space forms the Dehn function is at most quadratic while in NIL and SOL case it's at least cubic.

Comment: @SamNead Thank you for your answer! I'm confused by one point: if we take for granted "a closed three-manifold is a spherical space form if and only if it has finite fundamental group" then wouldn't the Poincaré conjecture be immediate from the classification of spherical space forms? Or is this a consequence of the geometrization theorem?

Comment: @YvesCornulier Your answer is a bit over my head, could you expand it to a full answer? For example where do these fundamental group restrictions come from?

Comment: @youler - The Poincare conjecture follows from the classification of (spherical) space forms which in turn follows from geometrization.  Perelman really did deserve that Fields medal!